# set controls properties at main uiview from other uiview

Tags: objective-c

I have main controller:

```
@interface BallsViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *InfoLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextBallButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ViewBoard *viewBoard;

- (IBAction)addNextBalls:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewBoard is UiView on which I draw. Sometimes I want to send to controller information that user can not draw anymore. This information will be set to label and button used to draw should be disabled.

How can I achieve that in proper mvc way ?

Comment: A BOOL property is needed in your BallsViewController. Which will suggest to draw or not.

Comment: ok, but how can I change it from uiview?

Comment: View doesn't send anything. That is the work of model and controller.

Answer (score 1):

You want to send information *from* the view *to* the view controller about whether or not drawing is enabled, right?  It's not going to really match the MVC pattern because in that pattern your view objects shouldn't be modifying the state of the program, but oh well.  Let's use a common iOS/Mac OS pattern instead:

Define a delegate protocol for your view, like

```
@protocol ViewBoardDelegate
- (void)viewBoardDrawingDidEnable:(ViewBoard *)sender;
- (void)viewBoardDrawingDidDisable:(ViewBoard *)sender;
@end
```

something like that anyway.  Now make your view controller support that delegate protocol and make the view controller the delegate of your ViewBoard.  When the viewBoard wants to change the enabled state it can then use the delegate methods, like:

```
[self.delegate viewBoardDrawingStateDidEnable:self];
```

or

```
[self.delegate viewBoardDrawingStateDidDisable:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation:

```
 -(void)stopDrawing{
nextBallbutton.enabled= false;
 //more code you need
}
```

Call this method whenever you need to stop drawing. If this needs to be called by `viewBoard`, then add a weak reference to your BallsViewController in it and send messages to it.

Comment: so I should in uiview create few properties and in controller I change behavior of controls depends of them ?